# find and move files based on file name pattern using linux script

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to sort two different file name patterns into two different folders.

The two file name patterns are:

- name contains: s00 or e00 or s00e00 or s0e000 or 0x00 - where 0 =
  digits [0-9]

and

- name contains a valid 4 digit year
- name does not contain: s00 or e00 or s00e00 or s0e000 or 0x00 - where
  0 = digits [0-9]

Comment: Sounds like you want a shell script solution, I'd suggest adding the tag bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will move the first group to folder1:

```
mv *s[0-9][0-9]* *e[0-9][0-9]* *s[0-9]e[0-9][0-9][0-9]* *[0-9]x[0-9][0-9]* folder1
```

With those files out of the way, this will move the ones with something that looks like a valid year to folder2:

```
mv *19[0-9][0-9]* *20[0-9][0-9]* folder2
```

Here, I assumed that a "valid year" was going to be between 1900 and 2099.

Comment: You are also including years 10xx and 29xx.

Comment: @tripleee  Good point.  I updated the answer with something a bit more restrictive.  The spec for the year requirement is a bit loose. My solution above would, for example, identify 20141103 as a valid year.  Whether that is correct behavior or not is to the OP to decide.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to John1024.

Here is a script for recognizing and separating movies & tv shows. Just make sure to edit /path/to/tv-shows/ directory at the end of the first line, and also /path/to/movies/ directory at the end of the second line.

```
find "$TR_TORRENT_DIR/$TR_TORRENT_NAME" -type f -a -not -size -100M -a -not -size +2G -a -not -iname "*sample*" -a -iname "*s[0-9]*" -o -type f -a -not -size -100M -a -not -size +2G -a -not -iname "*sample*" -a -iname "*e[0-9]*" -o -type f -a -not -size -100M -a -not -size +2G -a -not -iname "*sample*" -a -iname "*s[0-9]e[0-9]*" -o -type f -a -not -size -100M -a -not -size +2G -a -not -iname "*sample*" -a -iname "*s[0-9]e[0-9][0-9][0-9]*" -o -type f -a -not -size -100M -a -not -size +2G -a -not -iname "*sample*" -a -iname "*[0-9]x[0-9][0-9]*" -exec cp {} /path/to/tv-shows/ \;

find "$TR_TORRENT_DIR/$TR_TORRENT_NAME" -type f -a -size +500M -a -not -iname "*sample*" -a -not -iname "*s[0-9]*" -a -iname "*19[0-9][0-9]*" -o -type f -a -size +500M -a -not -iname "*sample*" -a -not -iname "*e[0-9]*" -a -iname "*19[0-9][0-9]*" -o -type f -a -size +500M -a -not -iname "*sample*" -a -not -iname "*s[0-9]e[0-9]*" -a -iname "*19[0-9][0-9]*" -o -type f -a -size +500M -a -not -iname "*sample*" -a -not -iname "*s[0-9]e[0-9][0-9][0-9]*" -a -iname "*19[0-9][0-9]*" -o -type f -a -size +500M -a -not -iname "*sample*" -a -not -iname "*[0-9]x[0-9][0-9]*" -a -iname "*19[0-9][0-9]*" -o -type f -a -size +500M -a -not -iname "*sample*" -a -not -iname "*s[0-9]*" -a -iname "*20[0-9][0-9]*" -o -type f -a -size +500M -a -not -iname "*sample*" -a -not -iname "*e[0-9]*" -a -iname "*20[0-9][0-9]*" -o -type f -a -size +500M -a -not -iname "*sample*" -a -not -iname "*s[0-9]e[0-9]*" -a -iname "*20[0-9][0-9]*" -o -type f -a -size +500M -a -not -iname "*sample*" -a -not -iname "*s[0-9]e[0-9][0-9][0-9]*" -a -iname "*20[0-9][0-9]*" -o -type f -a -size +500M -a -not -iname "*sample*" -a -not -iname "*[0-9]x[0-9][0-9]*" -a -iname "*20[0-9][0-9]*" -exec cp {} /path/to/movies/ \;
```

Then you can add this to the bottom of the script which removes and deletes torrents that have finished seeding. You will need to replace username and password in both spots.

```
transmission-remote --auth=username:password -l | grep Finished | \
awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n 1 -I % transmission-remote --auth=username:password -t % --remove-and-delete
```

Comment: If your `find` supports `-exec +` you can change the tail to `-exec cp -t /path/to/copies +` for a rather significant performance boost.

Comment: @triplee I'm not to familiar with what you are saying. Could you give me an example? Please. Thank You!

Comment: The repeated arguments could be significantly refactored with the use of parentheses.  Off the top of my head, `find /path/to/files -type -f -not -size -100M -not -size +2G -not -iname "sample" \( -iname "s[0-9]" -o -iname "e[0-9]" -o -iname "s[0-9]e[0-9]" -o -iname "s[0-9]e[0-9][0-9][0-9]" -o -iname "[0-9]x[0-9][0-9]" \)` but I'm not sure I managed to capture all of the intricacies of your complicated expression.

Comment: `-exec thing {} \;` will spawn a separate `thing arg` for each `arg` returned by `find`.  By contrast, `-exec thing +` will run `thing arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4` for as many arguments as possible in one go.

Comment: @tripleee Your Awesome!